# Restrict querying MongoDB collection to inactive chunks only

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am building an application which will perform 2 phases.

1. Execute Phase - First phase is very
   `INSERT` intensive (as many inserts
   as the hardware can possibly can
   execute in a second). This is
   essentially a logging trail of work
   performed.
2. Validation Phase - Next
   phase will query the logs generated
   by phase 1 and compare to an
   external source and perform an
   `UPDATE` on the record to store some
   statistics. This process is second priority to phase 1.

I'm trying to see if its feasible to do them in parallel and keep write locking to a minimum for the execution phase. I thought one way to do this would be to restrict my Validation phase to only query from older records which are not in the chunk currently being inserted to by the execution phase. Is there something in MongoDB that restricts a `find()` to only query from chunks that have not been accessed in some configurable amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mentioned replica set with slaveOk, and update in the master.

You can use a timestamp field or an ObjectId (which already contains a timestamp) for filtering.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will check the documentation to figure out the syntax. My immediate question is will this necessitate two connections (one for writes, one for reads) or can it be done case-by-case? I'm sure this will be clear after reading more docs.

Comment: you need definitely different connections as master and slave(s) should be on different hosts. BTW I thought those 2 phases are executed by different processes, competing each other..

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to set up replica set. Insert into the master and fetch from secondaries. In that way, your insert won't be blocked at all.